# Делегаты и события

Tags: c#

Создать класс Банк, с использование события ввода пин-кода(если неверный, повторить попытку) снятие и пополнение на счет.
Класс создал, но с пин-кодом никак не получается.

```
class Bank
    {
        public Bank(int sum)
        {
            AccountSum = sum; 
        }

        public int AccountSum { get; set; }

        public void PutSum(int sum)
        {
            AccountSum += sum;
            Check?.Invoke($"На счет поступило {sum} руб.");
        }

        public void TakeSum(int sum)
        {
            if (AccountSum >= sum)
            {
                AccountSum += sum;
                Check?.Invoke($"Со счета снято {sum} руб.");
            }
            else
            {
                Check?.Invoke($"На счете недостаточно средств.");
            }
        } 

        public delegate void AccountMessage(string message);
        public event AccountMessage Check;


    }
    class Program
    {
        public static void Message(string message)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(message);
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        { 

            Bank b = new Bank(150000); 
            b.Check += Message;
            b.PutSum(1000);
            Console.WriteLine($"Cумма на счете {b.AccountSum} руб.");
            b.TakeSum(50000);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

Comment: что именно не получается с пин-кодом ? в вести пин-код или проверить его ?

Comment: а что не получается? напишите функцию Authorize(string pin), в ней устанавливайте переменную класса (если pin правильный, его можно в конструкторе задавать) и проверяйте переменную в остальных методах. Кстати, непонятно, почему класс называется Банк, хотя это счет. Я думаю одного класса в данном бизнес-процессе будет недостаточно.